# Удаление файлов

Tags: php

Добрый день уважаемые. Есть папка в этой папке есть вложенные папки с множеством фаилов со вложеными папками причем колличество вложенных папок не постоянное как можно с помощью скрипта удалить все папки и со всеми вложенными папками и фаилами вобщем обнулить деррикторию ???

Comment: смотри в сторону: system с параметрами rm -ri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уточнить комментарий [[@vv2cc](/users/7163/vv2cc)](/users/7163/vv2cc) , то вот так:

```
system("rm -rf $directory_name");
```

P.S. Можно рекурсивно всё вычистить:

```
function removeDir($dir){
    if($objs = glob($dir."/*")){
        foreach($objs as $obj) {
            is_dir($obj) ? removeDir($obj) : unlink($obj);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$site="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
 $dirname = ("../gallery");
///////////
function delet_dir($delfile) //обзываем функцию. ниже- порядок ее действий
        {
          if (file_exists($delfile)) //если файл/каталог создан - продолжай
          {
            chmod($delfile,0777); //выстави атрибут на файл/каталог 777,т.е. полный доступ
            if (is_dir($delfile)) //если это каталог - продолжай,если файл - выполни действия после "else"
              {
                $handle = opendir($delfile); //открой каталог
                while($filename = readdir($handle)) //цикл чтения и запись всего в переменную
                  if ($filename != "." && $filename != "..") //в явном виде отменяем запись в переменную текущий и родительсткий каталоги, чтобы не потерять нужные данные
                  {
                    delet_dir($delfile."/".$filename); //удаляем файлы в каталоге          
                  }
                closedir($handle); //закрываем каталог                   
                rmdir($delfile);  //удаляем уже пустой каталог
              }
            else                   //если это все таки это не каталог
              {
               unlink($delfile);    //удали файл
              }
          }
        }
//функция определена.
//можно вставять в код.
//ниже -определение параметров(удаляемый каталог) и вызов функции
$deldir = ("../gallery/").($_GET['remove']);//задаем переменной нужный нам каталог. можно путь в явном виде. в данном примере подразумевается что $fotodir и $id заданы раньше:)
if (file_exists($deldir)) {delet_dir($deldir);}    //если находим его - удаляем
///////////
if ($_GET['remove'])
{
 if( !delet_dir($_GET['remove']))
 {
    echo "Папка <font color='#FF0000'>".$_GET['remove']."</font> и всем содержанием<br/> в каталоге <b>$dirname</b> была спешно удалена !!
    <html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='5; URL =admin_uploads_addir_img.php'></head>";
 }
 else echo "Ошибка!<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='5; URL =admin_uploads_addir_img.php'></head>";
}
else echo "Неверный запрос!<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='5; URL =admin_uploads_addir_img.php'></head>";
```